# Finding the Caltech101 class and Record in OpenImaj

Tags: java, maven, openimaj

I am trying this tutorial http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/classification101.html and this code is failing for me:

```
GroupedDataset<String, VFSListDataset<Record<FImage>>, Record<FImage>> allData = 
            Caltech101.getData(ImageUtilities.FIMAGE_READER);
```

The reason is that *Record* and *Caltech101* are not recognized and can't import them. All the other classes work fine.

Here is my maven dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>image-processing</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.openimaj</groupId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I also tried adding all the other dependencies from their website, http://www.openimaj.org/index.html but with no luck.

If anybody that had expirience with OpenImaj, if they could help that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [`image-annotation`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openimaj/image-annotation/1.3.1) Maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openimaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>image-annotation</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that `compile` scope is the default scope so you can't omit it.